# Cannot get nodes using kubectl get nodes with gcloud shell

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

My GCP GKE cluster is connected to the Rancher (v 2.3.3) but it shows unavailable with the msg:
*Failed to communicate with API server: Get https://X.x.X.x:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system?timeout=30s: waiting for cluster agent to connect*

When I try to connect to the GCP K8s Cluster via gcloudshell I cannot retrieve any info with command: kubectl get nodes !!

Any idea why it is happening ... all workloads and services are running and green, only Ingress stuff is with warning info some of them with Unhealthy status from the backend services. But first need to know how can I troubleshoot the problem with connectivity to the k8s cluster with gcloud or rancher !!

Comment: First try to run this command in your Cloudshell in order to connect to your GKE cluster if you did not: gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --region REGION --project PROJECT_ID. then run kubectl get nodes or any other kubectl commands. Are you getting any error messages in your cloudshell? sounds like a networking issue, make sure your pod networking is fine and do Curl to your Rancher to see what is going to return.

Comment: Fixed! 
Yes - you are correct that it was a networking issue! - but very long story to tell all things that we did! - Anyway thank you!

Comment: Nice! This is helpful for the community to add an answer as this issue has been fixed :)